# Fastest Open Source Java Application Server

Tags: performance, java, open-source, application-server

Which Open Source Java Application Server is the fastest?

- Glassfish
- Jetty
- JBoss

Others?

Comment: Is Jetty really comparable to Glassfish and JBoss?  Isn't it more at the feature level of Tomcat?

Comment: I heard, that it is lightweight but full AS compatible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have heard good things about Resin as well.
It has been a while since I've used JBoss, but at the time (>5 years) it was excellent.  Hopefully support is better now since it's more mature and Red Hat supported.

Answer (score 3):

I heard that Glassfish is the fastest server if you scale up to a big environment. 
This does it by [grizzly](https://grizzly.dev.java.net/).

Here are some [performance stats](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jfarcand/archive/2006/03/can_a_grizzly_r.html).

Comment: data is good...

Comment: We are using grizzly (without whole glassfish) for our custom file-sharing solution. We have 4gb/s bandwidth loaded per server with single Xeon 3570.

Answer (score 2):

it's discussable how much open source it is - but also take a look at [resin](http://caucho.com/resin/).